# Create triangle with rounded corners

Tags: android, draw, shapes

I need to create triangle with rounded corners. Here is my code

```
<item android:gravity="center">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%"
        android:toDegrees="45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" >
            </solid>

            <stroke
                android:color="#ffffff" />

        </shape>

    </rotate>
</item>
```

with my code only one side of triangle is rounded, other two corners not rounded. Please help me to create triangle all corners rounded.

Comment: In which drawable folder did you keep this file?

Comment: I keep it just in drawable folder.

Comment: Could you try to apply radius for different 4 attributes?

Comment: I try it too, not working

Comment: use svg drawable instead of simple shape

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Create `triangle.xml` into `res/drawable`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp"
        android:viewportHeight="16.0"
        android:viewportWidth="16.0" >
    <path android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent" 
          android:pathData="M11.844,9.04L8.345,5.163c-0.195,-0.217 -0.511,-0.217 -0.705,0l-0.012,0.02L4.136,9.04c-0.195,0.217 -0.195,0.569 0,0.786l0.006,0.005C4.233,9.936 4.358,10 4.499,10h6.983c0.143,0 0.27,-0.068 0.359,-0.176l0.002,0.002C12.039,9.609 12.039,9.257 11.844,9.04z"/>
</vector>
```

change color of triangle by changing `android:fillColor`

and use `@drawable/triangle`

it's easy way....
because simple drawable doesn't have advance features for shape modification.

Comment: How can I change pathData to set more rounded corners?

Comment: use [Inkscape](https://www.inkscape.org/) or [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) to create or modify svg. then create vector drawable from local svg in your android ide.

Comment: you can create any kind of shape using above tools. for your android app.

Comment: 1 .open Inkscape 2. draw shape 3. press Shift+Ctrl+S 4.Select Plain SVG(*.svg) 5.Save.

Comment: then open this [link](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) to convert SVG to VectorDrawable

Comment: Inkscape is sure a must have for android studio projects, as it is easy to create required shapes fast enough.